# returning multiple variables in JSON/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

Basically, i'm using an JSON response from a **local PHP file** to append data inside a div, currently it's only returning one variable, in which the code i'm using is shown here :

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "functions/ajax.php",
        data: "func=auto",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data.search, function (i, v) {
                    $div = $('.bs-docs-example');
                    $div.append('+ v +');
            });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log('Error ' + jqXHR);
        }
    });
```

The code which is returning the JSON is currently

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
     $search[] = $row['number'];
}
echo json_encode($search);
```

What i want to do is something like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
     $search[] = $row['number'];
     $search[] = $row['name'];
}
echo json_encode($search);
```

But if i was to do the following, how would i access both `number` and `name` since in the `success` on the jQuery it's parsing using `$.each(data.search, function (i, v) {` which means the original `$search[] = $row['number']` is now stored inside `v`

would i do something like `v['name']` `v['number']` or is that completely wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to pass an associative array to json_encode:

```
$search['number'] = $row['number'];
$search['name'] = $row['name'];
json_encode($search);
```

Or, if there will be multiple rows of results, as an array of associative arrays:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $search[] = $row;
}
```

And then access the values in JavaScript by name:

```
var name = v['name'];
```

Or

```
var name = v[0]['name']
```

If you're using multiple rows of results.

Comment: You could just drop the while loop and do json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($res)), I believe, assuming there isn't a reason to only pass in those two columns specifically.

Comment: Yes you could; I left the loop in case some preprocessing needed to be done to the rows, e.g. if not all returned columns are desired in the JSON output.

Comment: Perfect exactly, with little but very exact explanations +1